Distribution of angle between two vectors after a random projection
Suppose we have two vectors $\mathbf{x}$ and $\mathbf{y}$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ such that the angle between $\mathbf{x}$ and $\mathbf{y}$ is some fixed value $\theta$. Consider a $2$-dimensional plane $\Pi$ through the origin which is chosen uniformly at random. Let $\mathbf{x}'$ and $\mathbf{y}'$ denote the orthogonal projections of $\mathbf{x}$ and $\mathbf{y}$, respectively, onto $\Pi$. What is the resulting distribution of the angle between $\mathbf{x}'$ and $\mathbf{y}'$?
Additional Information: I am primarily interested in the case of large $n$, in case that simplifies things. I was able to show that (in the limit of large $n$) the inner product of $\mathbf{x}'$ and $\mathbf{y}'$ follows a variance-gamma distribution with PDF given by
$$f(\langle \mathbf{x}',\mathbf{y}'\rangle = z) = \frac{\sqrt{|z|}}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sin\theta}\exp\left(\frac{\cos\theta}{\sin^2\theta}\,z\right)K_{\frac{1}{2}}\left(\frac{|z|}{\sin^2\theta}\right),$$
where $K_m$ is a modified Bessel function of the second kind. I'm not able to compute the corresponding PDF for the case of the angle however. The additional normalization seems to complicate things.
For more details on the distribution of $\Pi$, let $Z$ be a $2\times n$ matrix with i.i.d. entries from the standard normal distribution (see this question). For large $n$, the rowspace $\Pi$ of $Z$ will essentially be uniformly distributed over the Grassmannian of $2d$-subspaces. The orthogonal projections of $\mathbf{x}$ and $\mathbf{y}$ onto $\Pi$ will have the same angle (to leading order in $n$) as the $2d$ vectors $Z\mathbf{x}$ and $Z\mathbf{y}$. In essence, it is the distribution of the angles between $Z\mathbf{x}$ and $Z\mathbf{y}$ that I am interested in.

Does plane $\pi$ go through origin?

@goldboy Yes. Thank you for pointing that out. I've edited the question for clarification.

I guess by $\mathbf{x}'$ and $\mathbf{y}'$ you mean the orthogonal projections of $\mathbf{x}$ and $\mathbf{y}$, respectively, onto $\Pi$.

Also it is not clear to me what is the uniform distribution on the set of all $2$-dimensional planes passing through the origin.

@AlexRavsky Yes, I mean the orthogonal projection. By uniform distribution I mean the standard distribution over the Grassmannian. In the large $n$ limit, this corresponds to drawing a $2\times n$ matrix $Z$ with iid standard Gaussian entries. The rowspace of $Z$ is uniformly distributed over the Grassmannian. The rows of $Z$ will be essentially orthogonal in the large $n$-limit as well, so we can equivalently consider $\mathbf{x}'$ and $\mathbf{y}'$ in local coordinates on the plane, i.e., $Z\mathbf{x}$ and $Z\mathbf{y}$ will have the same distribution of angles.

Shouldn’t it depend on the norm of the vectors. Are you assuming that $x,y$ are normalized?

@LPZ You can assume $\mathbf{x}$ and $\mathbf{y}$ are normalized if necessary (and that's the case for the result about inner products I wrote about). I fail to see why normalization is necessary for the case of the angle though, since that's a homogeneous quantity.

Not sure if this simplifies, but maybe assume that $x,y$ are chosen randomly (using some spherically symmmetric distribution, eg a  Gaussian), with the constraint $\delta({<x,y>\over |x||y|}-c)$ and look for projection on the first two axes.
